# else if wordpress issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to edit my header.php file to display a different image based on the language of the page.
If its the english site it displays the first clause and if the homepage is in dutch I want it to display the second clause. However, the code below is not working. Would anyone have suggestions?
Thanks

```
<?php
if(is_home()||is_page(885)||is_page(883)||is_page(276)||is_page(285)||is_category( '13' )){
echo'<div class="header3">
<a href="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/?page_id=285"><img src="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/wp/wp-content/uploads/what.jpg"></a>';

} 
elseif(is_home()&&(bloginfo('language')=="nl")){
echo'<div class="header3">
<a href="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/?page_id=285"><img src="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/wp/wp-content/uploads/whatnl.jpg"></a>';
}

else{
echo '<div id="branding2" role="banner">
                <div><img src="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/wp/a_flash/top.jpg"  /> ';
} ?>
```

Comment: Unrelated but: Your should not use **bloginfo('language')** unless you want to output the language locale, instead use **get_bloginfo('language')**, furthermore, the locale can be more than 2 characters like fr_FR, so you should compare the first characters only **substr(get_bloginfo('language'), 0, 2) === 'nl'**

Comment: This belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
// NL home
if(is_home() && substr(get_bloginfo('language'), 0, 2) === 'nl'){
    ; 
}

// Those pages or that category
else if(is_page(885, 883, 276, 285) || is_category(13)){
    ; 
}

// Default behaviour    
else{
    ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `is_home()` is hit right from the beginning so it doesn't have a chance to make it to the second option. Try:

```
<?php
if(is_home()&&(is_page(885)||is_page(883)||is_page(276)||is_page(285)||is_category( '13' ))){
echo'<div class="header3">
<a href="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/?page_id=285"><img src="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/wp/wp-content/uploads/what.jpg"></a>';

} 
elseif(is_home()&&(bloginfo('language')=="nl")){
echo'<div class="header3">
<a href="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/?page_id=285"><img src="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/wp/wp-content/uploads/whatnl.jpg"></a>';
}

else{
echo '<div id="branding2" role="banner">
                <div><img src="http://www.toolsfornetworkers.nl/wp/a_flash/top.jpg"  /> ';
} ?>
```

Notice `&&` instead of the `||` on the first line.